# c++: How to receive variable length output array from a function

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab

I am writing a wrapper in C++ which calls another C++ function.  But the output of that function is a variable length array. Unfortunately, array size needs to be compile time constant.

Current what I have:

```
double output[5];
mycustomfunction(input1,input2,input3,output);
for(unsigned i=0;i<(sizeof(output)/sizeof(double));i++)
   cout << ',' << output[i];
```

But I don't know how much will be the size of output until I run the function. I need to make the output declaration as dynamic.

Note: I cannot adjust mycustomfunction as it is machine generated code by Matlab coder. So it has to be an array.

Edit:
I gave [5] in this example for a test case where I know the output is 5, but generally I wouldn't know until I run.

Comment: Learn about how to use std::vector<double>. You may want to use this.

Comment: *But I don't know how much will be the size of output until I run the function* that's never going to work. So now you're using size 5, why is that, if you do not know what the size should be? Rewrite the function, eg split it in a function that gives you the size, and then the other part. For a proper answer, you should mention what exactly goes on inside mycustomfunction. I've done a lot of matlab/C++ interfacing and never had the problem you have, so something in your approach seems off.

Comment: You contradict yourself. If you declare `output` as an array with 5 elements, you know its size, and runtime isn't going to change it, no way. What's the signature of mycustomfunction?

Comment: If you aren't able to adjust `mycustomfunction`, how are you expecting to get the size?

Comment: What about `mycustomfunction(input1,input2,input3,output, size);` where size is passed as reference to set the maximum output size and to get the resulting size

Comment: @laune, I gave 5 elements for testing a case where I knew the size beforehand. But 99.9% of the time, I wouldn't know the size.

Comment: @DieterLücking, Even if I get the size as one of the output of the function, I still need to declare the output before that statement, right?

Comment: @Joe Yes same as before, define your tiny array and pass all information

Comment: I suspect the question is "given an arbitrary-but-typed pointer (e.g., a `double*`), how do I figure out how much data it points to?  Clearly `delete[]` has some way to know how many elements `new[]` allocated, and `free` has some way to know how many bytes `malloc` returned, how do I get that information?"  The answer is "the Standard does not give you any way to get that information, even though the system has to keep track of it internally.  Sorry.  There are very good reasons for this, one being that 'an arbitrary pointer' doesn't have to be allocated using `malloc` or `new[]` (or `new`)."

Comment: @MaxLybbert No, I think the question really is: "I have a function that takes a pointer where it is expected to write its output. The pointer should point to some available space that is enough for any call of the function, only I don't know how much this is." If so, an answer might be: "Allocate the maximum expected in your application (say, 1M) and say a prayer, OR throw away this function and find some other solution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, the C++ way to create a variable length array is with a `std::vector`.  [If you know the size of the array you need before you call `mycustomfunction`, you can even pass a `std::vector` as an array](http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/):

```
std::vector<double> arry;
arry.resize(5);
...
mycustomfunction(input1, input2, input3, &arry[0]);
```

However, if `mycustomfunction` expects to `realloc` the pointer passed into it, this will die.  Or, worse, it won't die and will instead [cause you heartache some other way](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213).

Otherwise, we'll need additional details about how `mycustomfunction` creates a variable length array, and how it reports the size to you.

---

There are C-style ways to deal with this, but they generally rely on the assumption that `mycustomfunction` will `malloc` the memory internally, and you will `free` it ([or that you will call some custom function to release the memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx?pageindex=1)).  Even then, `mycustomfunction` needs to either report the number of elements it created, or provide you some other way to find out how many elements it will create.  Broadly speaking, you have three common approaches:

#### `mycustomfunction` allocates memory for you, and tells you how much it allocated

```
size_t num_elements;
double* arry = mycustomfunction(input1, input2, input3, &num_elements);

for (size_t i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i) {
    ...
}
free(arry);
```

I would discourage this because it's very easy to forget to call `free` in some code path.

#### `mycustomfunction` allocates memory for you, and you have to find a special marker (e.g., [not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)) to know how much it allocated

```
double* arry = mycustomfunction(input1, input2, input3);

for (size_t i = 0; ; ++i) {
    double d = arry[i];
    if (d != d) { // only true for not-a-number
        break;
    }
    ...
}
free(arry);
```

This has the same problem that it's easy to leak `arry`. You also need to find a good value for your sentinel.  Not-a-number (or 0, or `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`, etc.) may well be a valid output.

#### you allocate the memory before calling `mycustomfunction`, and either have a way to know how much memory you need, or a way to tell `mycustomfunction` to not use more memory than you allocated

This is the approach I would recommend.  And it allows you to use a `std::vector<double>`:

```
std::vector<double> arry;
arry.resize(how_many_will_i_need(input1, input2, input3));
mycustomfunction(input1, input2, input3, &arry[0]);
...
```

Or:

```
std::vector<double> arry;
arry.resize(HOW_MANY_I_WANT);
mycustomfunction(input1, input2, input3, &arry[0], HOW_MANY_I_WANT);
...
```

Comment: So far, this is what I have been able to make it work. But if the actual arry size from the output is greater than 5, it gets truncated and if its less, the remaining elements are filled with zeros. I am not worried much about filled with zeros scenario and I can handle it. I can give an extremely large size for arry but not sure what are the other implications it might have.

Answer (score 2):

**The Pure C++ Solution: using `std::vector`**

In C++, for *dynamic* arrays, you should use **`std::vector`**. Its size can be dynamically changed (e.g. using `std::vector::resize()`, or adding elements using `std::vector::push_back()`, etc.), and `std::vector` knows its own size (e.g. calling `std::vector::size()`).

```
std::vector<double> DoSomething(...);
```

(Note that thanks to C++11 move semantics, even returning a very big vector is efficient.)

---

**The solution with C-isms**

If you can't use STL classes, an alternative is to use raw C pointers, and specify a size parameter (since raw C pointers don't know the size of the array pointed to).

```
// The caller passes a pointer to the allocated output array, with specified size.
// The function fills the array with the result.
void DoSomething(/* some inputs ...*/, double* output, int outputSize);
```

Still another option is to allocate the array inside the function, and return it as the return value:

```
double* DoSomething( ..., int* resultSize);
```

or use a double-pointer in the parameter list:

```
// Output array allocated by the function.
// The caller must free it.
void DoSomething( ..., double** output, int * resultSize);
```

Anyway, the `std::vector` solution is the best "pure C++" solution. The others are kind of *"C-isms"*.

Comment: I think you mentioned too many things in your answer. Returning a raw double* is not a good solution and is arguably incorrect.

Comment: Please: int& resultSize

Comment: Dieter: See e.g. Google’s C++ style guide. A pointer makes it clearer that the function may change the variable.

Comment: @Petter: Are you referring to the `double* DoSomething(..., int* resultSize)` case? The function can do a `new[double]` inside (or `malloc()` or whatever), and gives the pointer to the caller via return value. The size of the array is specified in the parameter list. What's wrong with it (apart the fact that we are not using `std::vector<double>`, which was what I suggested first, but maybe is not compatible with Matlab interop?)?

Comment: @DieterLücking: Yes, of course references can be an alternative. But  I'm start thinking that the OP wants some form of pure C interface for some interop with Matlab...

Comment: @Petter An answer returning an `std::vector` does not apply. Question specifically says `mycustomfunction()` cannot be touched.

Comment: @Petter: I separated what would be a pure C++ answer from the asnwers with a more C-like interface (which may be better for an interop with other systems like Matlab).

Comment: *A pointer makes it clearer that the function may change the variable* clearer than an argument passed by mutable reference? Does not make a lot of sense, plus a pointer should be checked for not being nullptr as well. Pretty sure I could find other style guides that agree with me :]

Comment: @Mr.C64 Petter is referring to, in the google style guide, we can argue whether or not it is "good" all day. But google basically favored knowing which arguments are inputs and which are outputs over making everything references. http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Reference_Arguments It is an arbitrary decision. I like it, others don't, but the discussion is out of scope :-/

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: I agree with you, and I fully understand Google's reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ `std::vector` ([link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) can be used as a container with contiguous memory chunk for data resized dynamically according to your needs. You can use a template to retrieve array size and assign values to a `vector`:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void copy_from_array(vector<T> &target_vector, const T (&source_array)[N]) {
    target_vector.assign(source_array, source_array+N);
}
```

usage:

```
std::vector<double> vd;
double output[5];
//... initialize output
copy_from_array( vd, output);
```